# cannot import gi module python 3.6 on mac

Tags: python, homebrew, pygobject

I am integrating gstreamer and pocketsphinx on mac using python 3.6; however, the first line of code, **from gi import pygtkcompat**, raises an error.
The command:

```
python3 demoapp_chinese.py
```

returns

> - Traceback (most recent call last):
> - File "demoapp_chinese.py", line 1, in
> - from gi import pygtkcompat
> - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

Here's how I install pygobject:

```
brew install pygobject3
```

And when I try to get more info. I execute

```
brew info pygobject3
```

which returns

> - pygobject3: stable 3.30.4 (bottled)
> - GNOME Python bindings (based on GObject Introspection)
> - https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject
> - /usr/local/Cellar/pygobject3/3.30.4 (69 files, 1.6MB) *
> - Poured from bottle on 2019-02-04 at 17:21:21
> - From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pygobject3.rb
>     (here I only post the first few couple of lines)

For the python info,

```
which python3
```

returns

> /usr/local/bin/python3

Besides,

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

returns

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

```
echo $PATH
```

returns

> /Users/cindy/bin:/usr/local/bin/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public

Lastly, I don't know if this is normal, when I run

```
which pygobject3
```

NOTHING returns on the terminal.

Please help, thanks. If you need any extra info. to help me, please let me know.